# How to remove item from Array?

Tags: swift, uitableview, swift4

I have a multi selected tableview.

**what I am doing :** when user select items, this items append to the array.

When user deselect the item from cell, this deselected items remove from array.

**what I did :**

**My array** : `var selectedTagList:[Tag] = []`

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        self.tagTableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .checkmark
        self.selectedTagList.append(tagList![indexPath.row])

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        self.tagTableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .none
        self.selectedTagList.remove(at: indexPath.row)
    }
```

Any advice or sample code please ?

**//DataSource and Delegate**

```
extension PickVideoViewController : UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate {

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        guard let tlist = self.tagList , !tlist.isEmpty else { return 1}
        return tlist.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let tlist = self.tagList , !tlist.isEmpty else {
            let cell = UITableViewCell()
            cell.selectionStyle = .none
            cell.backgroundColor = .clear
            cell.textLabel?.textAlignment = .center
            cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.black
            cell.textLabel?.text = "nodataavaiable".localized()
            return cell }
         let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TagCell", for: indexPath) as! TagCell
         cell.tagName.text = tlist[indexPath.row].tag
         cell.accessoryType = cell.isSelected ? .checkmark : .none
         cell.selectionStyle = .none // to prevent cells from being "highlighted"
         return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        self.tagTableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .checkmark
        self.selectedTagList.append(tagList![indexPath.row])

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        self.tagTableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .none
        self.selectedTagList.remove(at: <#T##Int#>)
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        guard let tlist = self.tagList , !tlist.isEmpty else {return tableView.frame.height }
        return 40

    }

}
```

Comment: So what is the issue?

Comment: the issue is when ı remove : out of bounds

Comment: can you show your UITableViewDataSource?

Comment: if you select the 10th cell, and it is your second selection. the array will only contain 2 items. you are attempting to then remove at index 9. which is out of bounds.

Comment: If you insert number 7 and number 9 to an array it will have two items. 
Then you try to remove the 7th item. See the problem here?

Comment: So how can I remove deselected item ?

Comment: Btw. I don't know what you are trying to do but UITableView already manages this list for you.

`var indexPathsForSelectedRows: [IndexPath]? { get }`

[link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614864-indexpathsforselectedrows)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to maintain a list of selected items. You already have all of the items and the tableView can tell you which rows/items are selected.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614864-indexpathsforselectedrows

> **Discussion**
>
> The value of this property is an array of index-path
> objects each identifying a row through its section and row index. The
> value of this property is nil if there are no selected rows.

You are trying to reinvent the wheel. Always check the documentation for existing functionality.

If you then want a list of selected items from this you just create an array of the items at those index paths, something like this: (untested)

```
let selectedItems = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows().map {  
     self.tagList[$0.row] 
}
```

This code will iterate over the index paths and return the item from the array at each one. (this is untested, you may need to use flatMap as you are changing the type)

Answer (score 0):

```
self.selectedTagList.remove(at: indexPath.row)
```

`indexPath.row` is the wrong value to remove. Since your data source populates based on `tagList` and not `selectedTagList`, you need to get the item out of `tagList` and find the equivalent item in `selectedTagList`.

You don't show what type of object is in `tagList`, but you will probably need to make them conform to `Equatable` so you can do this lookup. Once you do, you should have something like this:

```
let deselectedTag = self.tagList[indexPath.row]
// You will need the items in `tagList` to conform to `Equatable` to do this
guard let indexOfDeselectedTag = self.selectedTagList.index(of: deselectedTag else) {
    // Data inconsistency: the item wasn't found in selectedTagList
    return
}
self.selectedTagList.remove(at: indexOfDeselectedTag)
```